# Can I define template variables for a block?

Tags: theming, blocks

I thought that I could define my own variables in the `build` method of my custom block, but it does not work. Here's an example block definition:

```
/** ... Provides a 'Blubb' block ... @Block ...*/
class Blubb extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    return array(
      '#output' => 'Blubb',
      'output' => 'Blubb'
    );
  }

}
```

I render the block in with this twig template:

```
Output: "{{ output }}"
```

And find that the `output` varialbe is empty. The template displays just:

```
Output: ""
```

Does Drupal not want me to use varialbes in block templates?

**Edit**: I'm using Drupal 8.